# Claim of a conditional probability identity

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A text on distributed detection (Varshney, 1997) makes a claim on conditional probability identities: If $p\left(u = 0 \vert x, H \right)$ is a conditional density for a binary random variable, given data $x$ and hypothesis $H$, and if $p\left(x \vert H \right)$ is a conditional density for the same data $x$, give hypothesis $H$, the claim is:

\begin{equation}
\int dx \cdot p\left(u = 0 \vert x, H \right)p\left(x \vert H \right) = p\left(u = 0 \vert H \right)
\end{equation}

I apologize for this (vague?) notation that appears in the book. Notation aside, I wonder if this is the Law of Total Probability, and I just cannot see it? I assume (again, notation unclear) that integration is over all $x$ where the integrand is well defined.

Comment: Allowing for the looseness in notation, $p\left(u = 0\mid  x, H \right)p\left(x \mid  H \right) = p\left(u = 0,x \mid H \right)$ and then the integral removes $x$

Comment: @Henry—so we just marginalize out $x$?